# Shade first row of table

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I want to shade the first row of a table that is displayed using DataGridView, and tie this to  a checkbox (i.e. the user selects "header row exists" and the background color for the first row of the grid changes).

What should I enter in the checkbox event to enable this?

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Similarly, I want to be able to shade columns by having the user specify a number. Will this work similarly to the shading of a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do the following:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // For shading rows
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    }

    // For shading columns
    int colNum = 2; // Add your own code to get the column number you want
    dataGridView1.Columns[colNum].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
}
```

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for, thanks! Though I've now realized that I need to undo the changes if the user unchecks the checkbox, so is there a way to do an if checkbox is unchecked, revert back to original background color?

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;